# 'instanceIndex=(0,)' caused exception SmiError as "ValueRangeConstraint(1, 2147483647) failed at: "0"" at Integer32

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I am new for python and SNMP (as well as pysnmp). After two weeks study, I wrote  a piece of python code which try to send a trap message.
The NotificationType was created by code:

```
   notification = NotificationType(ObjectIdentity('MY_MIB_FILE','myAlarmCleared'),
                                    instanceIndex=(0,),  
                                    objects={
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmId'):
                                            Integer32(111),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'mySystemDN'):
                                            self.DisplayString(''),  # currently a null string
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmNotificationSource'):
                                            ObjectIdentifier(
                                                (1, 3, 6, 1, 4)), # some dummy value
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myNotiSequenceNum'):
                                            Integer32(222),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmManagedObjectInstance'):
                                            self.DisplayString('SubNetwork=nw1,ManagedElement=my-1'),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmType'):
                                            self.AlarmType(3),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmProbableCause'):
                                            self.ProbableCause(307),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmSpecificProblem'):
                                            self.DisplayString('test alarm'),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmPerceivedSeverity'):
                                            self.AlarmSeverity(6),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmTime'):
                                            self.DateAndTime(OctetString(self.get_current_date_and_time())),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmAdditionalText'):
                                            self.DisplayString('alarm testing'),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmName'):
                                            self.DisplayString('system_testing_alarm'),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmServiceUser'):
                                            self.DisplayString('Dapeng Jiao'),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmServiceProvider'):
                                            self.DisplayString('Unknown Service Provider'),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmSecurityAlarmDetector'):
                                            self.DisplayString('Unknown Alarm Detector'),
                                        ('MY_MIB_FILE', 'myAlarmADMC'):
                                            Integer(1)
                                    }
                                    )
```

when I execute this code, I got following SmiError:

```
  File "/vagrant_data/snmpAgent/SOURCES/snmp_notifier_v3.py", line 142, in notifier_start
    cbFun=cbfun
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/ntforg.py", line 145, in sendNotification
    vbProcessor.makeVarBinds(snmpEngine, varBinds),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/varbinds.py", line 51, in makeVarBinds
    varBinds.resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/rfc1902.py", line 1143, in resolveWithMib
    objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity(*notificationObject+self.__instanceIndex).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/rfc1902.py", line 504, in resolveWithMib
    raise SmiError('Instance index %r to OID convertion failure at object %r: %s' % (self.__args[2:], mibNode.getLabel(), sys.exc_info()[1]))
pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: Instance index (0,) to OID convertion failure at object 'myAlarmTime': ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueRangeConstraint(-2147483648, 2147483647)), ValueRangeConstraint(1, 2147483647)) failed at: "ValueRangeConstraint(1, 2147483647) failed at: "0"" at Integer32
```

It seems pysnmp doesn't like to add suffix .0 for the variable whose syntax is defined as:

```
Integer32().subtype(subtypeSpec=ValueRangeConstraint(1, 2147483647))).setMaxAccess("readwrite")
```

Does it a bug for pysnmp? 
Or I should not add that .0 suffix?(at least after remove that '0,' from instanceIndex the code can be executed and trap message sent successfully. 
But I was told that

> A scalar variable has single instance and is identified by suffix .0 .
>   The object identifier (OID)  with .0 suffix indicates a scalar variable (i.e., single instance) (eg, analogous/category  of  a “table” with only one column)
>   Each of the varbinds in the notification is scalar for this alarm notification.

So seems the .0 is anyway needed, right? Or there are some misunderstanding from us?

Thanks in advance.

Br,
-Dapeng Jiao

The original MIB defination for that variable is:

```
myAlarmCleared NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    OBJECTS {
        myAlarmId,
        cesSystemDN,
        myAlarmNotificationSource,
        cesNotiSequenceNum,
        myAlarmManagedObjectInstance,
        myAlarmType,
        myAlarmProbableCause,
        myAlarmSpecificProblem,
        myAlarmPerceivedSeverity,
        myAlarmTime,
        myAlarmAdditionalText,
        myAlarmName,
        myAlarmServiceUser,
        myAlarmServiceProvider,
        myAlarmSecurityAlarmDetector,
        myAlarmADMC
    }
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION
        "This notification is generated when an alarm is cleared."
    ::=  {  myAlarmNotifications  3  }

myAlarmTime OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  DateAndTime
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION
        "This variable is the time of this Alarm object."
    ::=  {  myAlarmEntry  9  }

myAlarmEntry OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  myAlarmEntry
    MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION
        "A row containing one alarm."
    INDEX   { myAlarmId }
    ::= { myAlarmTable 1 }
```

and converted python format is:

```
myAlarmCleared = NotificationType((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, xxxx, x, xx, x, xxx, x, 6, 3)).setObjects(*(
("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmTime"), ("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmName"),
("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmServiceUser"), ("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmSpecificProblem"),
("MY-MIB-FILE", "cesSystemDN"), ("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmProbableCause"),
("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmType"), ("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmAdditionalText"),
("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmNotificationSource"), ("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmId"),
("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmManagedObjectInstance"), ("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmADMC"),
("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmSecurityAlarmDetector"),
("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmPerceivedSeverity"), ("MY-MIB-FILE", "cesNotiSequenceNum"),
("MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmServiceProvider"),))

myAlarmEntry = MibTableRow((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, xxxx, x, xx, x, xxx, x, x, x, 1)).setIndexNames((0, "MY-MIB-FILE", "myAlarmId"))
if mibBuilder.loadTexts: myAlarmEntry.setDescription("A row containing one alarm.")

myAlarmTime = MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, xxxx, x, xx, x, xxx, x, x, 1, 1, 9), DateAndTime()).setMaxAccess("readonly")
if mibBuilder.loadTexts: myAlarmTime.setDescription("This variable is the time of this Alarm object.")
```

DateAndTime was imported from SNMPv2-TC.

Answer (score 0):

One update for this:
Even the exception shows the problem is caused by 'myAlarmTime'

```
pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: Instance index (0,) to OID convertion failure at object 'myAlarmTime': ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueRangeConstraint(-2147483648, 2147483647)), ValueRangeConstraint(1, 2147483647)) failed at: "ValueRangeConstraint(1, 2147483647) failed at: "0"" at Integer32
```

But after debug, it seems the real issue is 'myAlarmId' syntax definition. As that variable is the only one defined with Integer32 with range (1, 2147483647)

```
myAlarmId = MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, xxxx, x, xx, x, xxx, x, 4, 1, 1, 1),
                            Integer32().subtype(subtypeSpec=ValueRangeConstraint(1, 2147483647))).setMaxAccess("readonly")
```

And after I change its value range to (0, 2147483647), the 
    instanceIndex = (0,)
start to works.

But I should NOT change that right?
Then what should be the root cause for this issue?
Pysnmp bug?
or our misunderstanding for SNMP and MIB file?

BTW: the suffix .0 was working fine with a Java based SNMP cilent. But due to company's order and license issue, we need to re-implement it and we though python should be a good enough to do this.

Attach more MIB definition relate to this alarm event

```
myAlarmTable OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  SEQUENCE OF myAlarmEntry
    MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION
        "A table of all the active alarms on the system."
    ::= { myAlarmObjects 1 }

myAlarmEntry OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  myAlarmEntry
    MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION
        "A row containing one alarm."
    INDEX   { myAlarmId }
    ::= { myAlarmTable 1 }

myAlarmEntry ::=
    SEQUENCE {
        myAlarmId                   Integer32,
        mySystemDN                  DisplayString,
        myAlarmNotificationSource           OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
        myAlarmManagedObjectInstance        DisplayString,
        myAlarmType                 AlarmType,
        myAlarmProbableCause            ProbableCause,
        myAlarmSpecificProblem          DisplayString,
        myAlarmPerceivedSeverity            AlarmSeverity,
        myAlarmTime                 DateAndTime,
        myAlarmAdditionalText           DisplayString,
        myAlarmName                 DisplayString,
        myAlarmServiceUser              DisplayString,
        myAlarmServiceProvider          DisplayString,
        myAlarmSecurityAlarmDetector        DisplayString,
        myAlarmADMC         INTEGER
    }


myAlarmId OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  Integer32 (1..2147483647)
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION
        "This object uniquely identifies an entry in the
        Alarm Table. It increases every time a new alarm
        occurs. Due to cleared alarms the index will not be
        contiguous. When the maximum is reached of
        Integer32, the value of this object rolls over to 1."
    ::=  {  myAlarmEntry  1  }
```

Br,
-Dapeng Jiao